# Conversion of integer to filename incorrect fore more than one digit

Tags: loops, fortran, writefile

```
Program main 
use ifport 

implicit none
integer ii,fileid 
double precision pi
logical result
character*256 path,filename,fileNum
pi = 4.d0*datan(1.d0)
ii = 20
path = './testforlder'

result = makedirqq(path)

Do ii = 1, 11

fileid = 1 + ii
write(fileNum,"(A10,I1,A4)") "/TimeStep-",ii,".txt" 
filename = trim(path)//trim(fileNum)
open(unit = fileid,file=filename,status='unknown')
write(fileid,*) "The result is:", ii,pi,2*pi
close(fileid)

End Do  

pause
End Program
```

My code is written as above. When the loop step is less than 10, it works. However, when the loop step >= 10 (for example: 11), it fails.

Comment: How does it fail? Does it create a file called `TimeStep-*.txt`? You are restricting yourself to single digit integers when generating `fileNum`.

Comment: It could only generate 9 files. But it should generate 11 files.

Comment: Use `I2.2` to get numbers like 01,02,...

Comment: @MichaelO. Thanks, I got the answer.

Comment: Or use I0, see the link and **numerous** other duplicates for many examples.

Comment: @VladimirF thx!